# function output of a tuple of 2 arrays, into a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

new to Python (matlab background).

I have a function (`np.unique`) that can output either 1 or 2 arrays:

1. array of unique values.
2. counts for each value (enabled by setting an argument `return_counts=true`)

When the function is set to return a single array only, assigning the result into the undefined variable `"uni"` makes it an `ndarray` type:

`uni=np.unique(iris_2d['species'],return_counts=False)`

But when the function is set to return 2 arrays the variable `"uni"` is created as a `tuple` containing 2 `ndarrays`.

Is there a way to force the output directly into a 2d array (and multidimensional in general), without predefine the variable `"uni"` **or** using a a second function like `numpy.stack`/`numpy.asarray`?

```
import numpy as np

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'

names = ('sepallength', 'sepalwidth', 'petallength', 'petalwidth', 'species')
dtype=np.dtype({'names':names, 'formats':np.append(np.repeat('float',4),'<U16')})

iris_2d = np.genfromtxt(url, delimiter=',', dtype=dtype, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])

uni_isTuple=np.unique(iris_2d['species'],return_counts=True)

uni_isNdArray=np.unique(iris_2d['species'],return_counts=False)
```

Comment: Normally we'd use `uni, cnt = np.unique(..., return_count=True)`.  That is, assign the tuple elements to different variables.  The code is clearest that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a way to force `np.unique()` to return a ndarray instead of a tuple. I realize you asked for a solution that doesn't call another function, but if you'll tolerate passing the tuple to `np.array()` to build a ndarray from the tuple that might give you what you want.

```
uni_isTuple = np.array(np.unique(iris_2d['species'],return_counts=True))
```